# Make The First Photo of The Galleria Facebook Album The Actual Facebook Album's Cover Photo

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-graph-api, image-gallery, galleria

I'm trying to find a way to call the Fb album’s cover photo to be the first photo of the Galleria gallery working with the galleria-facebook plugin ([HERE](https://github.com/aiaio/galleria-facebook)).

The idea would be that the foremost photo displayed be the Fb album's cover photo.

Because I’m seeing the Fb graph query in the plugin's JS file doesn’t call for the “cover_photo” field, I’m trying to tweak it by inserting that call but I can’t figure out where I would have to insert that cover photo so that it becomes the first photo in the pile, as it were.

Any ideas how?

Answer (score 0):

So I haven't been able to solve this yet. Truth be told, I was forced to leave the project for a time as is. but hopefully I'll be able to get to working on it again very soon. Or, better yet, maybe the *galleria-facebook* plugin team might come up with such an option for the plugin. I'll share for you guys their response to a suggestion I posted in their GitHub project repository:

> Thanks for the feature request. I think this is a valuable
>   feature for the plugin to have. We'll try to make progress on this in
>   short order and report back with some progress. Also open to any
>   source code contributions that could speed it along.